# How do I pass my Array of Objects through dispatch using redux

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, react-redux, react-hooks

I am trying to pass an entire array of objects through my dispatch, but currently can only pass one array item at a time, I need them all to be passed through.

So far I have got the whole set up working with one array item and am fine with the mapping and displaying of the data in the destination component.

I have tried too many things to list, this is my third question ever and only ask if I am REALLY stuck. Hopefully it's something simple for someone else though!

Here is the code, if I am missing anything please let me know:

**My object interface:**

```
export interface Project {
  id: string,
  name: string,
  fields: any[],
  client: string,
  timeline: string,
  website: string,
  thumb: any[],
  images: [{ src: string, id: string }],
  icons: [{ src: string, id: string }],
  intro: string,
  desc: string,
  url: string,
  git: string,
  gitUrl: string,
  completed: boolean
}
```

**My store:**

```
import { configureStore, Action } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { ThunkAction } from 'redux-thunk';

import rootReducer, { RootState } from './reducers/rootReducer';

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer
});

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export type AppThunk = ThunkAction<void, RootState, null, Action<string>>;

export default store;
```

**My reducer:**

```
import { combineReducers } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

import projects from '../../features/slices/projectSlice';
import projectFilter from '../../features/slices/filterSlice';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  projects,
  projectFilter
})

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>

export default rootReducer
```

**Sending data through dispatch on page load:**

```
// import frameworks
import React from 'react';
import { useCallback, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { setProjects } from './slices/projectSlice';
// import projects
import projectData from '../data/projects.json';

// SetProjects
export default function SetProjects(): JSX.Element {
    // dispatch
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    // send resized and sorted data to dispatch
    const handleSubmit = useCallback((projects: any[]) => {
        dispatch(setProjects(projects));
    }, [dispatch]);

    // resize the current data array
    const resizeData = useCallback(
        (dataArray: any[], size: number) => {
            const resizedData = [].concat(dataArray).slice(0, size);
            handleSubmit(resizedData);
        },
        [handleSubmit]
    );

    // sort the current data array
    const sortData = useCallback(
        (dataArray: any[], size: number) => {
            const sortedData = [].concat(dataArray).sort((a, b) => (a.id > b.id ? 1 : -1));
            resizeData(sortedData, size);
        },
        [resizeData]
    );

    // sort data on page load (default to 9)
    useEffect(() => {
        sortData(projectData, 9);
    }, [sortData]);

    // buttons to show more or less projects
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => sortData(projectData, 18)}>SHOW MORE PROJECTS</button>
            <button onClick={() => sortData(projectData, 9)}>SHOW LESS PROJECTS</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**My slice. I keep thinking the problem is coming from here. I can add one from the array on each button click from SetProjects. I want to remove the [0].id and [0].desc and instead send through all 18 items each with their own id and desc so I can then map them on the display page and get the lot. Eventually my SHOW MORE and SHOW LESS buttons will reset the page and then only dispatch the correct number of array items.**

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

import { AppThunk, AppDispatch } from '../../redux';
import { Project } from '../types';

const initialState: Project[] = [];

const projectSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'projects',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setProjects(state, action: PayloadAction<Project>) {
                state.push(action.payload);
        },
        filterProjects(state, action: PayloadAction<Project>) {
            let project = state.find((project) => project.id === action.payload.id);

            if (project) {
                project.completed = !project.completed;
            }
        }
    }
});

export const { filterProjects } = projectSlice.actions;

export const setProjects =
    (projects: any[]): AppThunk =>
    async (dispatch: AppDispatch) => {
        console.log(projects);
        const setProjects: Project = {
            id: projects[0].id,
            desc: projects[0].desc,
            name: '',
            fields: [],
            client: '',
            timeline: '',
            website: '',
            thumb: [],
            images: [{ src: '', id: '' }],
            icons: [{ src: '', id: '' }],
            intro: '',
            url: '',
            git: '',
            gitUrl: '',
            completed: false
        };
        dispatch(projectSlice.actions.setProjects(setProjects));
    };

export default projectSlice.reducer;
```

What am I doing wrong here? I feel like it's getting "close" but frustrating at the moment.

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got this working by changing my setProject to this:

```
            const setProject: Project[] = projects.map((proj) => ({
                id: proj.id,
                desc: proj.desc,
                name: proj.name,
                fields: proj.fields,
                client: proj.client,
                timeline: proj.timeline,
                website: proj.website,
                thumb: proj.thumb,
                images: proj.images,
                icons: proj.icons,
                intro: proj.intro,
                url: proj.url,
                git: proj.git,
                gitUrl: proj.gitUrl,
                filtered: false
            }));
```

and my setProjects action to this:

```
        setProjects(state, action: PayloadAction<Project[]>) {
            action.payload.forEach((proj: any) => state.push(proj));
        },
```